# Running program in an environment w/ altered folders

Tags: virtualization, macports, sandbox

I am trying to run a legacy program (not mine) and trying to get it to run on an M1. I have managed to get it working contingent on this program being able to see a few files that it wants at a certain location in /opt/local/... . As long as those files are there, the program runs well (using Rosetta, which I am happy with).

Unfortunately, I am also running MacPorts, and various packages that I have installed with MacPorts need to see a different version of the same files, with the same name, in the same /opt/local/... location. I have tried all manner of things to get MacPorts to install these files elsewhere, but MacPorts likes doing things in /opt/local the way it does.

It would seem that what I need to do is get this program to think the thing it calls "/opt" is something other than what it is. That way, I can just put the files it needs in its virtual "/opt" folder and let MacPorts do its thing. Is there any easy way to do this? I was looking into some kind of chroot solution, except this is a GUI app with audio stuff happening and I'd have to copy all kinds of stuff into the chrooted /. Bind mounting would make that much easier but macOS doesn't have that unless I want to use something like bindfs. I guess could try something like a Docker container but as this is a GUI app with audio I'm not sure how well that'd work. I'm hoping to avoid really heavy virtualization (like running it in an entirely different OS in a VM) if at all possible. Is there some relatively simple way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Docker only runs Linux

Comment: Is the path hardcoded into the legacy application? Can you use a binary editor to change it to `/opx`?

Comment: @nohillside it seems to be hardcoded somewhere. I just tried doing that on a hex editor, but it still manages to look in /opt/local somehow....

Comment: Is the application available for download somewhere so others could try?

Comment: The program is called Scala and is available at https://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/downloads.html. The developer has it listed as officially supported only up to Mojave but it does work on macOS versions later than that, and even seems to work pretty well on M1 Monterey except for this problem with the GTK2. The bundled GTK2 installer puts a version of the x86_64 arch GTK in /opt/local. As long as those files are there, as well as the x86_64 versions of the various dependencies, things will run smoothly.

Comment: But if you have MacPorts, there will be arm64 versions of various things there instead; either the GTK2 library directly or some of those same dependencies. One possible solution was to try to build the gtk2 port with +universal, but that requires building *many* dependencies all with +universal and something in there seems to be broken. I've looked for some way to get the program to read those libraries some other directory, including hex editing /opt/local to /opt/loca2 within the binary, but something somewhere is still hard coded to look for /opt/local.

Comment: I'm in touch with the developer about it but in the meantime I would like to see if there is some clever way to get it to run even if MacPorts has its own stuff happening in /opt/local. Backup plan would be to run the Windows version in Parallels, I guess.